# Export Layers with Labels to DXF from QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, dxf

i have a problem with DXF-Export from QGIS. As shown below, the labels of my lines are not correctly exported to the DXF file.

What settings have I done wrong?

[image: Layout in QGIS]

These are the settings I use for Export:

[image]

And this is the result in the DXF:

[image]

Comment: Hi Toby, if I had known that you wanted to transfer the labels back into AutoCAD, I would have created the routine differently : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460665/callout-labels-with-more-lines/461075#461075

Comment: Hi Chris, do you habe a solution for that problem?^^ I would be very thankful if you could add the code to the other problem if you have some time left for that ^^ The problem is, that the final result needs to be exported to dxf, and there labels are not shown correctly anymore.